# How do I get the administrator to automatically flag?

Tags: 8, nodes, flags

I created a module for flagging entities automatically when created or updated.

There are some errors in my code because only nodes work.

If a user "user1" creates a node, the flag will be in his name. I want the flag to be done automatically on behalf of the site administrator.

How do I get the administrator to automatically flag?

```
use Drupal\flag\FlaggingInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
use Drupal\commerce_store\Entity\Store;
use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\Product;
use Drupal\group\Entity\Group;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\comment\Entity\Comment;

/**
 * Flag node.
 */
function admin_task_notify_node_update(Node $node) {
    $flag_id = 'moderate_node';
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    $flag_service->flag($flag, $node);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FlagServiceInterface::flag` takes an `$account` argument:

> The account of the user flagging the entity. If not given, the current user is used.

So for example:

```
$flag_id = 'moderate_node';
$flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
$flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
$account = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
$flag_service->flag($flag, $node, $account);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a PHP error. I updated my question.

Comment: Check the arguments, you have them the wrong way round

Comment: Thanks, it works. But how do I do for the "Flag User" part? Do I add `$account` twice

Comment: Just name the variables differently - use `$admin_account` for the admin account for example